# Crop and resize an image to use on a list

Tags: android, image, resize, crop, image-size

I need to crop and center an image to make a thumbnail for a list, but I want the size of the thumbnail to be proportional to the screen size, so that when the list is shown on a tablet or on a phone the image can be perceptible.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ImageView` to display the thumbnail.
Set the size of the `ImageView` in the layout XML, where you can set a different size for each screen size, by following this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Make sure the scale type of the `ImageView` is set according to your need by setting the correct `android:scaleType` property to your `ImageView`. The available scale types can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

That should do the trick.